# Add group to the net user with c# code

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ftp

I am working in asp.net  with C#. I need to create  ftp user with the code . i code for this requirement   but new requirement is  set diff diff folders for diff diff users .i think i need to create group and set groups to the user but  i tried a lot but not getting  any code for this requirement. Following is my current code that create a user for the  ftp user.

```
 ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
 procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
 procStartInfo.Arguments = "/env /user:" + "192.168.0.64/Administrator" + "cmd /K \"NET USER pky112 Admin123# /ADD    \"";

 procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

 ///command contains the command to be executed in cmd
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

 proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

 var sas=    proc.Start();
```

please suggest me new idea for this type of requirment

Comment: I don't understand, you want to connect to ftp with specific user credentials?

Comment: yes and  i also did this but now new requirement is  to set diff diff folder for diff diff users

Comment: So, as I understand, the snippet you posted is not relevant. you simply need a snippet to modify the folder's ACL to allow user 'diff' to access the folder. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set directory's security, use the following snippet:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
DirectorySecurity security = directory.GetAccessControl();
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule({ftp server user\'s sddl}, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
directory.SetAccessControl(security);
directory.Refresh();
```

Comment: security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule({ftp server user\'s sddl}, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
  please Explain this line

Comment: sddl is the user's unique identifier. this should be set to the ftp-SERVER user's sddl (since the server is the 'user' that physically accesses the file after it verified the 'diff/diff' user), the FileSystemRights member is an enum to describe the required privileges, InheritanceFlags describes weather to apply the access rule to sub folders as well, PropagationFlags also describes inheritance behavior, AccessControlType simply describes weather you want to Allow/Deny the access rule

Comment: security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Administrator", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

Comment: i tried this code this  code is not giving any error bt  it give the access of ful htp site i need to set the folder for new created user  but i am unable to do this

Comment: is snippet is work with my old code that i mentioned in the question

Comment: The ftp user is to be configured via the ftp server (whichever you are using - IIS, filezilla, winscp etc etc). In order to add a ftp user, you must first know which is the server and then find an API in order to modify its properties via c#. there is no 'universal' way of doing it.

Comment: means the requirement i wont to get is impossible

Comment: You will need to add reference to Microsoft.web.management.dll. read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.management.server.managementauthentication.createuser.aspx

Comment: i need to add group to the user